# Не запускается система Armbian Linux

Tags: orange-pi, armbian-linux

Ситуация такова - командой dd я записал файл .py в блочную директорию mmcblk0. После записи вроде все было ровно, но как только я решил прочитать директорию командой cat, полностью умерли шрифты. Попытался перезагрузить плату, но она не запускает систему. Как восстановить систему?

Comment: `командой dd я записал файл .py в блочную директорию mmcblk0` - какая еще блочная директория ?? mmcblk0 это [специальный файл устройства](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Специальный_файл_устройства) блочного типа. Для записи в него простых файлов _обычно_ нужно чтобы он был  примонтирован и имел какую-либо файловую систему которая и будет хранить эти данные. Скорее всего своими действиями вы убили на данном устройстве таблицу разделов если она там была и файловую систему, и если там была система на которой работала плата то она накрылась медным тазом, но до перезагрузки она висела в оперативке.

Comment: А есть способ это как то исправить, сохранив данные системы? Например найти нетронутый файл mmcblk0 и заменить его, вставив SD карту в другое устройство. И вопрос - как тогда корректо записать файл в eMMC?